# Проблемы перехода с листа на лист RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, мне нужно, что бы в recyclerView выводился список с категориями (фрукты, ягоды и т.д), далее при нажатии на фрагмент списка выводился следующий список из array с представителями этой категории и далtе при нажатии на представителя выходило окно с его описанием (которое хранится в string). 
Реализовала следующим образом, создала мой адаптер, с помощью его и выводу данные и описала действия при нажатии на элемент, но в итоге у меня данные не совсем корректно выводятся.
**ExampleActivity**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView tvDescription;
private ImageView imDescription;
private int category = 0;
private int position = 0;
private int [] array_berry_text = {R.string.berry_1, R.string.berry_2, R.string.berry_3};
private int [] array_image_berry = {R.drawable.im_berry_1, R.drawable.im_berry_2, R.drawable.im_berry_3};
private int [] array_fruits_text = {R.string.fruits_1, R.string.fruits_2, R.string.fruits_3};
private int [] array_image_fruits = {R.drawable.im_fruits_1, R.drawable.im_fruits_2, R.drawable.im_fruits_3};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.description_layout);
    init();
    reciveIntent();
}

private void reciveIntent() {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    if (i != null) {
        category = i.getIntExtra("category", 0);
        position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    }
    //переключатель категории
    switch (category) {
        case 0:
            tvDescription.setText(array_berry_text[position]);
            imDescription.setImageResource(array_image_berry [position]);
            break;
        case 1:
            tvDescription.setText(array_fruits_text[position]);
            imDescription.setImageResource(array_image_fruits[position]);
            break;
    }
}

private void init()
{
    tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    imDescription = findViewById(R.id.imDescription);
}
```

}
**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter;
private CustomArrayAdapter.CustomAdapterOnItemClicked customAdapterOnItemClicked;
private String[] array;
private ArrayList<ListExampleClass> listExample = new ArrayList<>();
private ListExampleClass listItem;
private int categoty_index;
private int position;
private int[] array_image_category = new int []{R.drawable.berries, R.drawable.fruits, R.drawable.nuts};
private int[] array_image_berries = new int []{R.drawable.ufhf, R.drawable.dnfhg, R.drawable.cmfu};
private int[] array_image_fruits= new int []{R.drawable.fffvf, R.drawable.efrs, R.drawable.vdfsd};

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
    NavigationView nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    customAdapterOnItemClicked = new CustomArrayAdapter.CustomAdapterOnItemClicked() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomAdapterItemClicked(int position) {
            if(position == 0) {
                openCategory(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.berries_array), array_image_berries, 0);
                initExample();
            }
            else if(position == 1)
            {
                openCategory(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruits_array), array_image_fruits, 1);
                initExample();
            }
        }
    };

/Переход на новые активности
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
{
    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.id_example)
{
    openCategory(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_array), array_image_category, 0);
}

 //Функция для открытия наших листов
public void openCategory(String[] array, int[] image, int index)
{
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rView);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));//Указываем что бы был вертикальным по умолчанию
    listExample = new ArrayList<>();
    customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(listExample, customAdapterOnItemClicked, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);
    for (int i = 0; i< array.length; i++)
  {
      listItem = new ListExampleClass();
      listItem.setNameE(array[i]);
      listItem.setImage_id(image[i]);
      listExample.add(listItem);
  }
    if (customArrayAdapter!= null)  customArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    categoty_index = index;
}

private void initExample()
{
    customAdapterOnItemClicked = new CustomArrayAdapter.CustomAdapterOnItemClicked() {
        @Override
        public void onCustomAdapterItemClicked(int position) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExampleActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("category", categoty_index);
            i.putExtra("position",position);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };

}
```

}

Получается при запуске мой список с категориями открывается корректно, далее при нажатии на первый элемент список с представителями и по нажатию на них все открывается корректно.
Но когда открываю вторую категорию - фрукты, список с представителями открывается, но при нажатии на представителя приложение перекидывает на представителей первой категории и дальше начинается вообще белиберда. Подразумеваю я ни правильно описала переход и передачу позиции в функции initExample(), либо неправильно что то прописала прослушивателе нажатий recyclerView. 
Подскажите, где напортачила, пожалейста?
Если что CustomArrayAdapter это мой адаптер посредством которого я и заполняю листы.

Comment: Вообще не понятно излагаете мысли. Вот например, что такое фрагмент списка? Возможно элемент? В андроиде слово фрагмент значит совсем другую сущность. Что значит список из array? Далее пишете листы) Напишите списки. И т.д. по тексту. А количество грамматических ошибок не сосчитать. Читать и разбираться нет никакого желания. Возможно поэтому вам никто и не отвечает.
Отредактируйте пожалуйста ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Circassian Спасибо большое! Даже не знаю как бы обошлась без вашего совета. Наверное пойду запишусь на курсы по русскому языку.

Answer (score 1):

Разобралась в проблеме. Не нужно передавать индекс при нажатии на ЭЛЕМЕНТ меню, нужно передавать индекс только при нажатии на непосредственно элемент выводимого списка. 
Поэтому в слушателе нажатий на элемент списка ничего не изменяла.
Добавила метод openExample, которую и использовала в переходе из меню в лист с категориями, аналогичный методу openCategory, только не прописывала в ней передачу индекса
То есть в переходе на активность необходимо прописать так:
openExample(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_array), array_image_category);